# Banner em IFRAME não abre nova Janela IOS e ANDROID

Tags: javascript, android, ios, apache-cordova, intel-xdk

Tenho uma aplicação que no footer eu coloquei um IFRAME que rotaciona os banners. Acontece que quando clica ele trava e não abre a nova janela com o site do anunciante.

Onde estou errando?

```
<iframe id='a177cc70' name='a177cc70' src='http://www.meudominio.com.br/www/delivery/afr.php?refresh=3&amp;zoneid=3&amp;target=_blank&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='320' height='50' allowtransparency='true'><a href='http://www.meudominio.com.br/www/delivery/ck.php?n=acf755b6&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.meudominio.com.br/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=3&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=acf755b6' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço demais

Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Se tu quer simplesmente que ao clicar no Iframe ele te leve para uma nova guia usa ao contrário, o `<a>` envolvendo o `<iframe>`. Assim:

```
<a href='http://www.meudominio.com.br/www/delivery/ck.php?n=acf755b6&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'><iframe id='a177cc70' name='a177cc70' src='http://www.meudominio.com.br/www/delivery/afr.php?refresh=3&amp;zoneid=3&amp;target=_blank&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='320' height='50' allowtransparency='true'><img src='http://www.meudominio.com.br/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=3&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=acf755b6' border='0' alt='' /></iframe></a>
```

Comment: Ola Thiago. Na verdade uso o Iframe para rotacionar meus banners e dessa maneira ele não funciona, pois se perde nas rotações... Teria alguma outra alternativa ?

Comment: O Problema todo reside no Iframe, me diz o seguinte em qual browser mobile tu testou?

Comment: Uso o Intel XDK mas crio o aplicativo e testo no meu Android. Ele rotaciona os banners normal mas quando clica ele trava.

Comment: Aí que entra o problema tu está rodando dentro de um App, correto? Não há nova janela para ele abrir, pois ele emula um browser no teu App para rodar esse IFRAME. O único jeito de fazer isso é fazendo uma chamada do teu App abrindo outro App (no caso o navegador) já na url desejada.

Comment: Entendi...você teria um exemplo para que eu possa seguir? estou bem perdido nisso e preciso finalizar...Obrigado